# Jquery Mobile - Unable to select the specific item from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile list. This list is populated with data.

I want to select a default item dynamically (through jquery).

This question has been asked many times but I have tried all the resolutions given but unable to figure out this problem.

The code is here http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/2/

Comment: _I want to select a default item *dynamically* (through jquery)_ Can you explain the terms *dynamically* here?

Comment: In my actual code there would be polling done to a webservice. This webservice will give the actual timezone of the user logged in. The timezone can be changed by the web interface as well, not only from mobile site. So in this case if the timezone has changed, I should reflect the same change on the mobile. I hope it is clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing i noticed is that you had two ids for your select menu.
I also changed your JQuery to `$('#select-choice-a').val('Africa/Tunis').selectmenu('refresh');`
Here is a jsFiddle showing it works http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/nMR85/4/

Comment: thanks a lot. I don't need two id's, I just overlooked that I had two id's .. :)